# Both USB Host and charging on android device

Tags: android, usb, microcontroller

I'm looking a way to achieve simultaneous OTG and charging on Android device. How does the device detect this?

My goal is to connect a self-powered custom Arduino-based board to an Android device, enabling both communication (via USB CDC UART port) and charging (from the board to the Android device) over USB-C port.

I've observed that when connecting this android device to a display with Power Delivery, both charging and USB communication are successful, so it is possible.
I am taking into account that the display I tested utilize CC pins.
I'm planning to design a custom board so I can also utilize different USB controller or emulate its functionality with a microcontroller.

I'm open to suggestions or guidance on how to achieve this successfully.

I know about ACA-Dock mode described in Battery Charging Spec v1.2 but it needs ID pin that do not exist in USB-C.